# arcgis javascript polygon don't work in 4.7 but do in 4.27

Tags: javascript, arcgis

this code works great. and you can see it in action here
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/?sample=sketch-geometries

but

change the javascript from 4.27 to 4.7 and the polygon suddenly doesn't work properly.

I need to use 4.7 and make polygon's so how can I fix this?

Thanks!

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>Sketch widget | Sample | ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript 4.27</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/"></script>

    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      require([
        "esri/widgets/Sketch",
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/views/MapView"
      ], (Sketch, Map, GraphicsLayer, MapView) => {
        const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

        const map = new Map({
          basemap: "topo-vector",
          layers: [graphicsLayer]
        });

        const view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          zoom: 5,
          center: [90, 45]
        });

        view.when(() => {
          const sketch = new Sketch({
            layer: graphicsLayer,
            view: view,
            // graphic will be selected as soon as it is created
            creationMode: "update"
          });

          view.ui.add(sketch, "top-right");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```